# What's mean of the below definition in boost library

Tags: c++, boost

I am studying boost library inside and puzzled by following definition:

```
namespace boost {
  namespace container {
    template<typename CharT, typename Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>, 
    typename A = std::allocator<CharT> > 
      class basic_string;
    template<typename CharT, typename Traits, typename A> 
      basic_string< CharT, Traits, A > basic_string< CharT, Traits, A > && 
        operator+(basic_string< CharT, Traits, A > basic_string< CharT,
        Traits, A > && mx, const basic_string< CharT, Traits, A > & y);
```

What's meaning of the type `basic_string< CharT, Traits, A > basic_string< CharT, Traits, A > && mx` ?Is this similar with the `long long int` type?
Here is the boost reference link: [boost 1.48.0](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_container_header_reference.html#header.boost.container.string_hpp)

Comment: Look at [std::basic_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) -- see any similarities?

Comment: @DanMašek No similarity example in std::basic_string.

Comment: What version of boost is this from? Which header? I can't find anything like it in any recent release.

Comment: Could you post a referenece to the code?

Comment: Can you add information of boost version, file and line where you found this?

Comment: Edited, boost 1.48.0, thank you.

Comment: I believe this is a mistake in the docs. I have the same (1.48.0) version of Boost installed and I don't find these kind of operator definition in header string.hpp while I see the ordinary ones. Moreover, your code doesn't compile with c++14 flag. However I may be wrong

Comment: @DimG May be the document administrator misinterpret the macro into two basic_string types, it makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, so this wasn't from the code, but from documentation? Just out of curiosity, if you're studying the library, why not study a version that's not 5 years old? You're throwing away years of work by many people and end up running into bugs that have [long been fixed](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_container_header_reference.html#header.boost.container.container_fwd_hpp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be an issue in the boost documentation, the template definition for `operator+` there looks like a syntax error for me. However inspecting the corresponding header file the definition looks like this:

```
template <class CharT, class Traits, class A> inline
BOOST_RV_REF_3_TEMPL_ARGS(basic_string, CharT, Traits, A)
   operator+(
   BOOST_RV_REF_3_TEMPL_ARGS(basic_string, CharT, Traits, A) mx
   , const basic_string<CharT,Traits,A>& y)
{
   mx += y;
   return boost::move(mx);
}
```

Where the macro `BOOST_RV_REF_3_TEMPL_ARGS` is defined as

```
#define BOOST_RV_REF_3_TEMPL_ARGS(TYPE, ARG1, ARG2, ARG3)\
TYPE<ARG1, ARG2, ARG3> && \
//
```

, which looks perfectly fine to me, and is different from the documentation.

Comment: May be the document administrator misinterpret the macro into two basic_string types, it makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Breaking this down bit by bit...

1) This is a template

```
template<typename CharT, typename Traits, typename A>
```

2) For a function that returns an rvalue reference to some type

```
basic_string< CharT, Traits, A > basic_string< CharT, Traits, A > &&
```

3)  The function is `operator+`

```
operator+(basic_string< CharT, Traits, A > basic_string< CharT,
    Traits, A > && mx, const basic_string< CharT, Traits, A > & y);
```

The `&&` bit is stating that it's an rvalue reference (although be careful, when templates come into play it's not always so...). This is much like the more familiar lvalue reference symbol `&`.

Comment: Thats not answering the question. The question is what is the type of the first parameter of operator+: `basic_string< CharT, Traits, A > basic_string< CharT,
    Traits, A >`

Comment: I suppose the TS was really wondering what "some type" (as you named it) means,  as it's formed as doubled basic_string<...> which is a type itself

Comment: re #2 what on earth is that though